# Parse a number but keep the negative's in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I'm trying to do.

Right now I can parse a number by adding commas automatically, however, when I try to type a negative it goes away.

Here is the current code that I'm using to parse the number:

```
      $(this).val(function(index, value) {
          return value
                .replace(/\D/g, "")
                .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            });
```

How do I keep the number negative value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\D` matches anything that isn't a decimal digit, so you're removing the minus sign. Use `[^-\d]` instead to remove anything that isn't a digit or minus sign.

```js
function add_commas(value) {
  return value
    .replace(/[^-\d]/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

console.log(add_commas('1234567'));
console.log(add_commas('-1234567'));
console.log(add_commas('-123,4X567'));
```

Caveat: this won't work correctly if they put a `-` in the middle of the number, since it will be left in the number.